# How to create array of coordinates?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, express, coordinates

I am working on geo location search in nodejs backend. And mongodb is the database. In order to do that, I am getting values from front end. I am using map getbound to get viewport data. Below are some variables that holds latitude and longitude.

```
  var topLeftLong = parseFloat(req.body.topLeftLong);
  var topLeftLat = parseFloat(req.body.topLeftLat);

  var topRightLong = parseFloat(req.body.topRightLong);
  var topRightLat = parseFloat(req.body.topRightLat);

  var bottomRightLong = parseFloat(req.body.bottomRightLong);
  var bottomRightLat = parseFloat(req.body.bottomRightLat);

  var bottomLeftLong = parseFloat(req.body.bottomLeftLong);
  var bottomLeftLat = parseFloat(req.body.bottomLeftLat);
```

Though I am getting these data, I want to put latitude and longitude in an array. But whenever I tried to push data in the array, I get the below error.

[image: This is error from mongodb (may be)]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like wrong data type is to blame. In your code if you applied cast, for e.g. (int)string-var, then it could be the error due to that. Data types are important. Mismatch data types would cause errors.